Is there a nuance in my sentence below?

You can't bring meat from abroad into Australia to prevent the spread of diseases.

A corrector on a language learning site said my sentence above could be ambiguous.

The ambiguity can be eased by reversing the order: To prevent the spread of diseases, you can't bring meat from abroad into Australia.

If you do not understand why an instructor on a 'language learning site' made that observation, why are you seeking an explanation here rather than asking the instructor? Isn't the very point of a 'language learning site' to enable one to learn such things on the site?

A quick and dirty fix uses a comma separator: You can't bring meat from abroad into Australia, to prevent the spread of diseases. Not flawless, but better.

Does this answer your question? What would you call this kind of prepositional phrase?

"You can't carry a gun to defend yourself" vs "You can't carry a gun to stop you shooting people".

It's ambiguous because "can't" can mean either "not possible" or "not allowed".
Presumably the intended meaning is that in order to prevent the spread of diseases, it's illegal to bring meat from abroad.
But another possible interpretation is that bringing meat from abroad is not a possible way to prevent the spread of diseases.
In reality, few people would find this actually confusing. Anyone who understands the relationship between uncontrolled food products and spread of disease would realize that the second interpretation is unlikely.
This ambiguity was exploited in a Saturday Night Live sketch where a retiring nuclear reactor manager tells his crew

You can't put too much water in the nuclear reactor.

After he leaves, they argue over whether he was telling them that it's safe to put as much water as you want in the reactor (because it's not possible to put too much) or warning them against overfilling the reactor (because you must not put too much).

It obviously can be ambiguous, if you don't mind my being forthright. The first interpretation is that you can't do that if you think it is a measure aiming at preventing the spread of diseases (several possibilities of prevention might be possible, one of them being betting on the soundness of foreign meat, which should thus contaminate nobody); Australian law would not permit this initiative. The second interpretation (most probable one) is that it is forbidden to do so because doing so would contribute possibly to the spread of diseases in Australia. A third is that you are confronted to an impossible situation: doing that does not prevent the spread of dseases because, for instance, it is an inefficient measure. Depending on what you want to say, other formulations will be preferable, unless the statement you intend comes after explanations that it summarizes, but then, still, certain writers might insist on greater specificity.

Your sentence:

You can't bring meats from abroad into Australia to prevent the spread of diseases.

can sound a little odd. Since "you can't do X to achieve Y" often has the meaning "X is the wrong approach if you want to achieve Y", your sentence lends itself to this paraphrase:  Bringing meat from abroad into Australia is the wrong thing to do if you want to prevent the spread of diseases.
But what people normally want to do is to state the rationale for a prohibition in a positive manner, rather than by saying that the prohibited thing  won't accomplish the goal. To state it in a positive manner, we put the rationale at the front of the sentence,  as @JimMack suggested in a comment above.

To prevent the spread of diseases (rationale, the goal), you can't bring meats from abroad into Australia. (the prohibition)

